# Luke 1:20 why plural demonstrative

Tags: luke

Why “these things” in Lk 1:20 when only the birth of John the Baptist and not the “things” he would do seems sufficient for Zacharias’ voice to return?

Comment: A suggestion: In your future postings, do not be afraid to "unpack" your questions. I had to read your question about a dozen times before I knew what you were getting at. If you had expanded your sentence into at least two--possibly more--sentences, I think I would have grasped your meaning more readily and easily. Welcome to SE Biblical Hermeneutics. Keep the questions (and answers) coming! Don

Answer (score 4):

Luke 1:13–20 (KJV)

> 13 But the angel said unto him, Fear not, Zacharias: for thy prayer is
> heard; and thy wife Elisabeth shall bear thee a son, and thou shalt
> call his name John.
>
> 14 And thou shalt have joy and gladness; and many shall rejoice at his
> birth.
>
> 15 For he shall be great in the sight of the Lord, and shall drink
> neither wine nor strong drink; and he shall be filled with the Holy
> Ghost, even from his mother’s womb.
>
> 16 And many of the children of Israel shall he turn to the Lord their
> God.
>
> 17 And he shall go before him in the spirit and power of Elias, to
> turn the hearts of the fathers to the children, and the disobedient to
> the wisdom of the just; to make ready a people prepared for the Lord.
>
> 18 And Zacharias said unto the angel, Whereby shall I know this? for I
> am an old man, and my wife well stricken in years.
>
> 19 And the angel answering said unto him, I am Gabriel, that stand in
> the presence of God; and am sent to speak unto thee, and to shew thee
> **these glad tidings.**
>
> 20 And, behold, thou shalt be dumb, and not able to speak, until the
> day that **these things shall be performed**, because thou believest
> not my words, which shall be fulfilled in their season.

Therefore the "these things" refers to the "glad tidings" and John would be mute until they were "performed", γίνομαι - meaning to come into being.

- thy wife Elisabeth shall bear thee a son
- thou shalt call his name John
- thou shalt have joy and gladness
- many shall rejoice at his birth.

Then there are predictions of the future, e.g. being filled with the holy spirit, a nazarene, cause many to repent, and great in God's sight, etc.

But Zacharias was mute until the first four came about and the second set began, and thankfully not until John's ministry was completed.

Comment: Good answer. +1.